# .git and .gitignore

Tags: git, github

If I:

```
$ mkdir rails-proj

$ cd rails-proj

rails-proj/$ git init
```

there will be `.git` **folder** and `.gitignore` **file** created. I opened `.git` folder, seems this folder stores all the *branch* and *commits* informations.

But I still need more information about the `.git` and `.gitignore` . What are they used for?

Comment: `man gitignore` and `man git` might help? What information are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Those are used by git, which is a version control system used by programmers. Check out these links:

http://help.github.com/set-up-git-redirect

http://progit.org/book/ch1-3.html

http://gitready.com/